# Combining columns in a SAS dataset

Tags: sql, sas

My question involves combining multiple columns in a dataset into a single column.  I know that this question has been answered several times before, but that was only for a single variable outside of a larger dataset.  This is for two variables in a larger data set.

Basically, here is what the data looks like:

```
Range Pass Height Height_1 Height_2 Height_3  V   V_1   V_2   V_3   Breed Treatment
2     6    200    .        .        .         20  .     .     .     AAAA  1
2     8    .      179      .        .         .   18    .     .     BBBB  1
2     10   .      .        199      .         .   .     21    .     CCCC  1
2     12   .      .        .        188       .   .     .     19    DDDD  1
3     6    155    .        .        .         17  .     .     .     BBBB  2
3     8    .      201      .        .         .   22    .     .     AAAA  2
3     10   .      .        195      .         .   .     20    .     CCCC  2
3     12   .      .        .        188       .   .     .     18    DDDD  2
```

So basically, I want to combine all four "Height" columns into a single Height column and all four "V" columns into a single V column while keeping all the other columns unchanged.

Comment: Curious, how did this data come to you?  That looks like it might've been transformed in a way that you could've transformed it more easily into your desired goal.

Comment: @Joe The data is that way because of how we collected it.  We used a field computer, and did everything based on distance from the start so that we could have multiple people recording data.  So at that point, all 8 variables were filled in all in a straight line.  Using the variables, we made a difference column (0, 2, 4, and 6) and added the difference and the starting point to get our pass value.  Breed, treatment, and our other variables were on a separate reference file, and we simply used the merge step to combine the two.

Comment: Sure, so when you do the "added the difference and the starting point" bit, why not just make `Height` rather than `Height` `Height1` etc.?

Comment: When I had the original data set, there were 4 columns labeled "height" and four labeled "V."  SAS added the numbers itself when I imported the set in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do this in SQL using `coalesce()`, which SAS `proc SQL` supports:

```
proc sql;
    select range, pass,
           coalesce(Height, Height_1, Height_2, Height_3) as height,
           coalesce(V, V_1, V_2, V_3) AS V,
           Breed, Treatment
    from dataset;
```